# Find $x_{0}$ if you knew that the tangent line is vertical

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions, tangent-line

Tangent equation at a point is $f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0}) + f(x)$

The problem is that I want to know $x_{0}$ if you knew that the tangent is vertical...so what I need to do?

The slope of the line isn't even 0, it's undefined.

Comment: I assume you have a specific function ? Check in which points the derivative is not defined.

Comment: Try finding it among the points where $f'(x_0)$ is undefined.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe how do I do that? How do I search for points where f'(x0) is undefined?

Comment: You would have to look at the expression. For example, if you have some terms that look like
$$
\frac{1}{\text{something}}
$$
then you'd be interested in the cases where this $\text{something}=0$.

Comment: Try to find the $x_0$ where $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is $\pm \infty$.

Comment: For example, let's take $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$. For $x\ne 0$ the derivative is not just well-defined but one can calculate it easily: $f'(x)=\frac{x}{2|x|^{3/2}}$. So the only candidate for a vertical tangent is for $x=0$. Now those points must be examined separately using the limits. (Most likely - the limits from each side in turn.)

Comment: @MattiP. Oh you mean the domain of the function. Got it! Thanks!

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I got it but what if there is too many points outside of the function's domain. Which one I choose?

Comment: @TechnoKnight Can you give us the function you are interested in ?

Answer (score 0):

If the tangent line is vertical at $x_0$, that means $$\lim_{x \to x_0} f'(x) = \pm \infty.$$ So try finding the asymptotes of $f'(x)$ and those should give you the values $x_0$ you're looking for.